# Comparing two Observables like an array with .forEach & .some

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I have an Observable that I'm binding to the view asynchronously, and I want to compare the values emitted by that Observable to another Observable to see if any of their values overlap.

I was previously doing this by having two Arrays of Objects one we can call CurrentUserFriends, and the other we'll call usersToCheck.

Now I wanted to compare the two Object Arrays and see if any of the values overlap (if you are friends with someone else's friend). So I set the value of `utc.isFriend = true` if they are a mutual friend, or `utc.isFriend = false` if they are not a mutual friend.

This is my checkIfFriend function:

`checkIfFriend(usersToCheck) { 
    return usersToCheck.forEach(utc => { return utc.isFriend = 
    this.currentFriends.some(cuf => cuf.uid === utc.uid);
}`,

Now, I want to allow Angular to handle the subscriptions for me by using the async pipe in the view, but I still need to find out if `usersToCheck[FriendID].isFriend` or not, but I'm not sure the best way to do this with Observables.

Here is the currentFriends observable which gets the current authed user's friends list:

```
currentFriends$: Observable<any[]> =this.profileService.getProfileFriends(this.auth.getUid());
```

And this is the $profileFriends Observable which gets the friends of the profile that you are looking at.

```
profileFriends$: Observable<any[]> =this.profileService.getProfileFriends(this.uid)
.map(friends => [...friends])
//.map(friends => this.friendsService.checkIfFriend(friends));
```

My current $profileFriends observable gives me the data if I take out:

```
    //.map(friends => this.friendsService.checkIfFriend(friends));
```

But I need that section for validation on the view. But I am not sure how to update checkIfFriend so that it can look at the data from both Observables, compare if a uid in one is in the other, and then set friendUid.isFriend to be true or false.

Edit: Here is my template for further clarification:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-list-header>Friends</ion-list-header>
<ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let friend of (people$ | async)">
  <ion-avatar (tap)="navToUserProfile(friend.uid)" class="avatar" item-left>
    <img src="{{friend?.image}}">
  </ion-avatar>

  <h4 (tap)="navToUserProfile(friend?.uid)">{{friend?.name}}</h4>
  <p>{{friend?.username}}</p>
  <p>{{friend?.isFriend}}</p>

  <ion-buttons item-end end>

    <button *ngIf="!friend?.isFriend" ion-button small (tap)="friendModal(friend)">Friends

    </button>

    <button *ngIf="friend?.isFriend" ion-button small (tap)="friendModal(friend)">Add Friend

    </button>


    <!--<button *ngIf="(!friend.isFriend && !friend.requestSent && friend.uid != this.auth.getUid())"-->
            <!--outline ion-button small (tap)="sendRequest(friend)">Add Friend-->
    <!--</button>-->

    <button *ngIf="!friend?.isFriend && friend?.requestSent"
            color="facebook" ion-button small (tap)="deleteRequest(friend)">Request Sent
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: what does `checkIfFriend` method do? it looks like you need a `filter` instead of the second map. also, where is the second Observable?

Comment: I updated the post to give more information @BorisLobanov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of how this can be done:

```
const friends$ = Rx.Observable.of([
    {id: 1, name: 'Mark'},
    {id: 2, name: 'John'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Adam'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Lucy'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Mary'}
]);

const people$ = Rx.Observable.of([
    {id: 11, name: 'Greg'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Lucy'}, // is a friend
    {id: 13, name: 'Julia'},
    {id: 14, name: 'Eugene'},
    {id: 1, name: 'Mark'} // is a friend
]);

// just some functions that imitate the delay
const getFriends = () => Rx.Observable.timer(800).switchMap(() => friends$);
const getPeople = () => Rx.Observable.timer(1500).switchMap(() => people$);


function checkIfFriend(friends) { // I used currying to be able to use map
   return person => {
     return Object.assign({}, person, {isFriend: friends.some(({id}) => person.id === id)});
  }
}

Rx.Observable.zip(getPeople(), getFriends()) // zip combines two streams and packages them into an array, which you can destructure later
    .map(([people, friends]) => people.map(checkIfFriend(friends))) // don't confuse the .map from rxjs with map from Array.prototype
  .subscribe(people => {
    console.log(people);
  })
```

Here's a working JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9d1tknjg/1/

**UPDATE**
Here's one way to dynamically change the text of the buttons:

```
<button ion-button small (tap)="friendModal(friend)">
    {{ friend?.isFriend ? 'Add Friend' : 'Friends' }}
</button>
```

Comment: Now will the Rx.Observable.zip that we're subscribing to resolve itself, or will I need to specifically unsubscribe from it at a later time?

Comment: Well, you can still use the async pipe instead of subscribing in the component. This is just for the sake of the example and also since you haven't provided the code for your template. Async pipe will manage the unsubscribing, however, if you resolve it in the .ts file you might want to unsubscribe manually.

Comment: You really deserve that 1,500! I have updated the question to include my template, if that helps you at all. I also wanted to say that your example works flawlessly, thank you so much. I just now need to get the View's buttons to change based on the friend ($people) value.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! Always happy to help! what seems to be the problem with the view?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the buttons to switch based on the value of $people/friend.

Comment: So like, if they are a friend, the button would show "Friends" and if they aren't friends, it would say "Add friend"

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, it's defaulting to the same behavior that it was before, where it just says 'Friends' for everyone, including users who are not friends.

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing something? Seems to be working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wxkhhc

Comment: I think i figured it out. People$ isn't being updated with the new values, and since we're using people$ in the view, it's defaulting the value. So I need to unpack the Observable.zip... that is being used, and assign the value to people$.